# Alguine me podrá orientar para saber porque no estan funcionando los comodines en este metodo? Tengo otro similar que si funciona les muestro ambos

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
public Page PedidosPorEstYnombreCliente (String establecimineto, String nombreyApellido, Pageable pageable){//busca pedidos por nombre de cliente y establecimiento asignado al usuario si este NO es admin
        
return pRepo.paginaPedidoPorEstablecimientoYnombreCliente(establecimineto,"%"+nombreyApellido+"%", pageable);
    }// lo que no funciona en este metodo son los comodines. Cuando los saco funciona bien pero me trae solo la busqueda exacta
```

y

```
public Page <Pedidos> buscarPedidoPorSubEstablecimieto(String subEst, Pageable pageable) { //Buscar Pedidos por SubEstablecimiento si el usuario es admin
        return pedidosRepo.listarPedidosXsubEstablecimiento("%"+ subEst +"%", pageable);
    }// en este funcionan perfecto los comodines
```

Ambos son métodos de la capa de servicios, que reciben parámetros del controlador y envían la info al repositorio para que este retorne la búsqueda. La idea es que el usuario pueda buscar de forma parcial algun nombre de cliente para que no tenga que ser una búsqueda exacta.

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Como que te falta decir que hacen esos metodos.. lo que mostras, no hace nada...

Comment: El metodo que no funciona lo que hace es buscar en la base de datos (MySQL) el pedido de un cliente por el nombre. Pero ademas lo filtra por el establecimiento que tiene asignado el usuario. Lo que necesito lograr con los comodines es que la busqueda no sea exacta sino que cuando el usuario ingrese las primeras 3 letras del nombre del cliente, el repositrio me devuelva todos los clientes que contangan esas 3 letras en el nombre. Por alguna razon no funciona, a diferencia del segundo metodo que solo busca por nombre de cliente y funciona bine. Espero ahora, se entienda un poco mejor...

Comment: por qué no usas spring data para el nombrado de tus métodos y te ahorras la mayoría de las implementaciones?

Comment: Ahhh tu problema es sql, QUE NO ESTAS MOSTRANDO.. y de paso, segun tu comentario, queres que haga una busqueda fuzzy en una cadena, no?? danos un ejemplo, pero lo que queres, segun me parece, no se hace asi.. y decir que el otro funciona, no tiene nada que ver, porque no hacen nada ni remotamente similar...

Comment: La verdad que esta comunidad me ha desilucionado, trate de buscar ayuda y lo unico que recibo es bardeo... evidentemente no es una comunidad para principiantes como yo... Gracias por nada